# How I set the select all text in the style when textbox got focus?

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, styles, selectall

I found only the way to select all text in the code behind. But i want to do it in the style of itself.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: no it is not possible in style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property that you can set to select all of the `Text` in a `TextBlock` or `TextBox`. Selecting all text must be accomplished using the [`TextBoxBase.SelectAll` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.selectall(v=vs.110).aspx). What you *could* do in a `Style` is to set an event handler for the `GotFocus` event, where the handler code would call `SelectAll`, but your handler would of course need to be in code and not XAML.

One other possibility would be for you to create an Attached Property that would select the text whenever the `TextBox` gets focus, but again it's not possible to do this in XAML.